# Access multidimensional array to single array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a multidimensional array like this coming from an POST;

```
array(4) { 
   ["id"]=> array(3) { 
        [0]=> string(1) "4" 
        [1]=> string(1) "5" 
        [2]=> string(1) "6" 
      } 
   ["deliverer"]=> array(3) { 
        [0]=> string(13) "x" 
        [1]=> string(12) "y" 
        [2]=> string(5) "z" 
      } 
   ["num_users"]=> array(3) { 
        [0]=> string(2) "10" 
        [1]=> string(2) "10" 
        [2]=> string(1) "5" 
      } 
   ["ADD"]=> string(6) "FORWARD" 
      }
```

I would like to associate the ID to the "deliverer" and the "num_users" in order to update a table in MySQL. I've tried both this way:

```
foreach ($_POST as $data){
    var_dump($data);
  }
```

and

```
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value){
    var_dump($value);
  }
```

But in both cases I ain't going in the right direction. I ain't so skilled so I wish to have some tips on how to proceed correctly.

Kind regards,

Chris

Comment: What kind of array would you like to have at the end ? Could you give us an example ?

Comment: Sure, array('id'=>'value', 'deliverer'=>'value', 'num_users'=>'value') for every index present in the multidimensional array. Cheers and thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php — it does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a potentital solution, depending on what you want in the end.

```
$datas = array();
foreach ($_POST['id'] as $k => $id) {
  $datas[] = array("id" => $id, "deliverer" => $_POST['deliverer'][$k], "num_users" => $_POST['num_users'][$k]);
}
```

---

An *"easier to understand"* solution would be :

```
$datas = array();
foreach ($_POST['id'] as $k => $id) {
  $datas[$k]['id'] = $id; // or $_POST['id'][$k]
  $datas[$k]['deliverer'] = $_POST['deliverer'][$k];
  $datas[$k]['num_users'] = $_POST['num_users'][$k];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ids = $_POST['id'];
$deliverer = array();
$num_users = array();
$num_usersRaw = $_POST['num_users'];
$i=0;
foreach ($_POST['deliverer'] as $k=>$v) {
  $id = $ids[$i];
  $deliverer[$id] = $v;
  $num_users[$id] = $num_usersRaw[$i];
  ++$i;
}
```

Explanation:

Get all the IDs first.

This will serve as the keys for `deliverer` and `num_rows` arrays.

Loop over `$_POST['deliverer']` and then assign key values to the two arrays: `$deliverer` and `$num_users`.

Comment: Plus 1 for the explanation.